# Sharepoint Activating a feature error: The resource object with key 'xxxxx' was not found

Tags: sharepoint, administration, toolkit

After succesfully installing the SharePoint Administration Toolkit and activating the PermissionReporting.wsp, the following reports error out:

**Broken Inheritance Reports Jobs** *- "The resource object with key 'StatusPageTitle' was not found..."* 
   **Check Effective Permissions** *- "The resource object with key 'AccountPageTitle' was not found..."*
   **Compare Permissions Sets** *- "The resource object with key 'TreeViewReportPageTitle' was not found..."*

I am relatively new to sharePoint and am not really sure what direction to go.  There has not been too much information on the errors related to this toolkit so any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution that resolved my issue:

Use cmd: **`stsadm -o copyappbincontent`,** *if copy command does not work copy the .resx file(s) from the resources folder to the Global resources folder, ie.*

**Source**  C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\CONFIG\Resources\test.resx

**Destination**  C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\\App_GlobalResources\test.resx

After files are copied, **restart IIS**